# Django server - 502 error bad gateway

Tags: django, nginx, config

I have a centOS with a virtualenv, i can use the project in my localhost , but when the project is upload to a server give an error :

502 - bad gateway

I think the problem probably is in my nginx file.

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name www.site.com.br site.com.br;
root /var/www/html/agrodez/src/;

if ($http_host != "www.site.com.br") {
    rewrite ^ http://site.com.br$request_uri permanent;

}
location /static/ {
    alias /var/www/html/site/src/sistema/static/;

}
location /{
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
    include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about django, but recently I had to help a team with server configuration, and I've used the following nginx virtualhost configuration:

```
upstream django.local {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000;
}
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  site.com;

    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        proxy_pass http://django.local/;
    }

    location /static {
        autoindex on;
        # this line would be STATIC_ROOT dir
        alias /var/www/html/agrodez/src/staticfiles;
    }

    location /media {
        autoindex on;
        # this line would be MEDIA_ROOT dir;
        alias /var/www/html/agrodez/src/media;
    }

    # If you want nginx logs, then can add these
    error_log /var/log/nginx/site.com_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/site.com_access.log;

}
```

You can give it a try.

Comment: also check the user permission. if you've setup virtualenv, and is running as a different user to nginx, then it might have trouble accessing files.